# match anything and stop when seeing word

Tags: regex

My test case is this: `this is a sentence. reviewed: name DEFECT: none`

I need to capture anything after `reviewed:` but stop when it sees `DEFECT:`

```
reviewed: (.+)(?=\sTASK|\sDEFECT)
```

above captures `name` correctly. But the problem is when there is no `DEFECT:` after match, like this

```
this is a sentence. reviewed: name
```

isn't matched. when changing the regex to

```
reviewed: (.+)(?=\sTASK|\sDEFECT)?
```

or

```
reviewed: (.+)(?=\sTASK|\sDEFECT)*
```

the match captures all `name DEFECT: none`. What should I use to stop the match after seeing the word `DEFECT:` **but at the same time the word may not be there at all**?

I have also tried the following with no luck:

```
reviewed: (.+)?(?=\sTASK|\sDEFECT)?
              ^
```

to make it non-greedy. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can just match the end of string with $, like this:

```
/reviewed: (.+?)(?=DEFECT:|$)/
```

Comment: good for this case, but not if there are other text afterwards :(

Comment: @mavili: Other text? If there are other keywords besides "DEFECT" that you need to match, just add them to the alternation: `(?=\sDEFECT:|\sTASK:|WHATEVER:|$)`  If there is more to it than that, please elaborate?

Comment: No I mean what if the text is `sentence. reviewed: by someone defect: none whatever blah` and I just wanna get `by someone`?

Comment: I re-tested my regex with that case, and it works (i.e., it captures "by someone"). How did you test it?

Comment: I'm not sure what I had tested it against, but I re-tested and now and it looks like it does the job. Thanks :)